# How do I scan the hexameter "faunique satyrique et monticolae silvani"? (From Metamorphoses I, 193)

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, ovidius, scansion

I was wondering if anyone knows how to scan this hexameter (complete source here https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Metamorphoses_(Ovidius)/Liber_I). Something that is usually short definitely needs to be lengthened for it to work (maybe the first -que?), but I don't know if there's any rule that allows this.

thanks

Answer (score 11):

You're right, the -e in the first enclitic is long. The reason is obscure, but is accessible in Allan and Greenough's (rev. Fowler 1890) student commentary on the *Metamorphoses*:

> 193. faunique : the enclitic -que is here used as long in imitation of Homer, who makes the Greek τε long. It is probably made so by the pause at the end of the word, or, as it is sometimes called, by caesura. This occurs generally in the second foot of the verse, and only when a second -que follows.

That the penult is a spondee is not so unusual, but should be noted as well. This gives you the following:

- faūnī|quē satyr|īqu' ,, ēt| mōntico|laē sīl|vānī

TKR in a comment below mentions a few additional examples:

> Lee's commentary adds some parallels:
>
> - Met. 4.10 *telasque calathosque*,
> - 5.484 *sideraque ventique*,
> - Verg. Aen. 3.91 *liminaque laurusque dei*.

Comment: Lee's commentary adds some parallels: *Met.* 4.10 *telasque calathosque*, 5.484 *sideraque ventique*, Verg. *Aen.* 3.91 *liminaque laurusque dei*.

Comment: @TKR Thanks! I didn't have a good commentary available, but I'll incorporate that into the answer soon.

Comment: That's very interesting, I had no idea τε could be long. I will look out for it.

Comment: In this particular line it doesn't matter because of elision, but if the first -que is long, is the second usually also?

Comment: @Kingshorsey In 5.484 and Verg. Aen. 3.91 the second e is short. In 4.10, it's elided into the next word (telasque calathosque infectaque pensa reponunt).